# Concatenate characters to a string - java

Tags: java, joptionpane

In Joptionpane my characters are shown one by one in the dialog message.
I need them to form a word , as for the example: if I use Sytem.out.println(c) it will show them in a line. I want to show them in a line together in joptionpane too

```
for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length(); i++) {
        char c = encrypt.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            c -= shift;
            if(c < 'A'){
                c = (char) (((int) c + (int) ('A')) % 26 + (int) ('A'));
            }else{
                c = (char) (((int) c - (int) ('A')) % 26 + (int) ('A'));
            }

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, c);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Then build a string of your characters. Right now you're just showing them one by one (as you describe) in a message dialog. Take this call out of the loop and build your string there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length(); i++) {
        char c = encrypt.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            c -= shift;
            if(c < 'A'){
                c = (char) (((int) c + (int) ('A')) % 26 + (int) ('A'));
            }else{
                c = (char) (((int) c - (int) ('A')) % 26 + (int) ('A'));
            }


        }
result += String.valueOf(c);
    }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);
```

Comment: THANK YOU, TOOK ME 6 hours to try everything  but u did it in 5 minutes
thanks a lot. I wish u all the best
i voted up however im a new user once i get more reputation ull get the vote

Comment: @dailyadd, if the answer covered your question you could accept it by clicking on the check.

Comment: Don't loop on string concatenation like this... Use a StringBuilder.

Comment: What @nickb said.  `result` should be a StringBuilder.  Never use += on a String in a loop, as it assigns a brand new String object to the variable each time.  If you had 1,000 characters, you'd end up creating 1,000 String objects that would all need to be garbage collected.

Comment: The question wasn't related to performance, it was about making the code work.